# Webgl rotate two triangles using offset in vertex shader without using transformation matrix

Tags: webgl

The goal of this task is to display two triangles on the canvas using the same vertex data and an offset to display the triangles and have them rotated in the vertex shader. I can get two triangles to display (comment out the window.requestAnimFrame(render, canvas); in my render function) how ever when trying to animate this code only one of the triangles displays, is there something really obvious I'm missing? Code below.

canvas display with requestAnimFrame commented out

[image: canvas display with requestAnimFrame commented out]

canvas display after trying to animate the triangles

[image: canvas display after trying to animate the triangles]

```
var fRotation;
var uOffset;
window.onload = function init()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);

    if (!gl) {alter("WebGL is not available.");}
    
    fRotation = 1;
    
    
    gl.viewport(0, 0, 512, 512);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    
    
    points = [
        vec2(-1, 0),
        vec2(1, 0),
        vec2(0, 1)      
    ];

    colors = [
        vec3(0, 1, 0),
        vec3(1, 0, 0),
        vec3(0, 0, 1)
    ];

    

    var program = initShaders(gl, vBasicShaderCode, fBasicShaderCode);
    gl.useProgram(program);
    
    var posBufferId = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, posBufferId);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var vPos = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aPosition");
    

    console.log("position data loaded");

    // load the data into GPU
    var colBufferId = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colBufferId);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // Associate shader variables with data buffer
    var vCol = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aColour");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vCol, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vCol);
    console.log("color data loaded");
        
    render();
    
    function drawtri(){
    
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPos);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, posBufferId);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPos, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        
        fRotation += 0.1 / 144;
    
        gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(program, "fRotation"), fRotation );  
        
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        
    }
    
    function render(){
        
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        drawtri();
        var uOffset = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uOffset"); // first need to get the location of the uniform variable
        var offset = vec2(0.3, 0.1); // we define 'offset' which is a 2 dimensional vector
        gl.uniform2fv(uOffset, offset); // we pass 'offset' to the variable in the Vertex Shader.
        drawtri();
        
        window.requestAnimFrame(render, canvas);
        
    }   
    
}
```

and the vertex shader

```
var vBasicShaderCode  =`
attribute vec2 aPosition; 
uniform vec2 uOffset; 
attribute vec3 aColour;
uniform float fRotation;
varying vec3 vColour;
void 
main() 
{
    
    
        
    vColour=aColour;
    vec2 uPosition = vec2(0.0,0.0);

    //translate

    uPosition.x = aPosition.x;
    uPosition.y = aPosition.y;

    
    
    vec2 transformedVertexPosition =  (aPosition + uOffset );
    
    uPosition.x = (cos(fRotation)*transformedVertexPosition.x)-(sin(fRotation)*transformedVertexPosition.y);
    uPosition.y = (cos(fRotation)*transformedVertexPosition.y)+(sin(fRotation)*transformedVertexPosition.x);

    //gl_Position = vec4(transformedVertexPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
     
    gl_Position = vec4(uPosition.x, uPosition.y, 0.0, 1.0);
    
}`;
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `uOffset` for every draw.

The code is effectively doing this

- uOffset = 0  // the default value
- render
- drawTri
- uOffset = 0.3, 0.1
- drawTri
- requestAnimationFrame
- render
- drawTri   // uOffset is still 0.3, 0.1 here. it doesn't magically go back to 0
- uOffset = 0.3, 0.1
- drawTri

Comment: Oh wow, I knew it would be something simple I just couldn't figure it out! Thank you. Changed the code to the below and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer to show the code that fixed this issue, thanks to Gman for the advice.

````
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);      
        var uOffset = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uOffset"); 
        var offset = vec2(0.0, 0.0); 
        gl.uniform2fv(uOffset, offset); 
        drawtri();      
        var offset = vec2(0.3, 0.1); 
        gl.uniform2fv(uOffset, offset); 
        drawtri();      
        window.requestAnimFrame(render, canvas);        
    }   ```
````